# How does paw handles download `application/octet-stream`?

Tags: paw-app

Most of the question is in the title.

I am trying to test an api that generates and streams large files. I am make the request with paw.

How does it handle the response?
Where are the downloaded files located?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to visualise the raw bytes in the "Text" tab, though maybe it won't help much:

[image]

Though, you can also enable the "Hex" tab in the Paw menu > Preferences > Response > "Show Hex Response Tab". Once you've that enabled you'll have a Hex formatted tab (note that there are known performance issues on the Hex tab for large responses, maybe > 500kB, we should work on improving it):

[image]

Also, you can export the body as a file as you pointed out. In File menu > Export Response > Response Body:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: That does answer my question, the thing that I left out in my question is that if the binary is big paw freezes.

Comment: Hum, sorry about that. It seems related to the text rendering engine taking forever on large binary contents. I suggest that you switch to the Headers tab, so it won't render the binary body. And then export the response as shown above to be opened by a 3rd party app.